VSCode Python Autopep8 argument wrapping
I'm using Autopep8 formatter in VSCode and struggling to get arguments to format the way I want.
Preference 1 - all arguments occupy one and only one line. e.g. arguments are not split over multiple lines.
Preference 2 - all function arguments on one line. (I realise this is non-preferred)
My problem is that my code is for a geometry based project with many 2d and 3d points. If it has one argument per line, that's an easy way to see 2 lines = 2d point. But the arguments contain mathematical expressions, so the formatter is also wrapping those expressions, which can make a 2d point look like a 3d point (at a glance) if one of the coordinates are wrapped.
Example:
pt1 = [originx, originy + fFrontHeight + fBackHeight]
pt2 = [originx + fFrontDropLength, originy +
       fFrontHeight + fBackHeight]

should become:
Preference 1
pt1 = [originx, 
       originy + fFrontHeight + fBackHeight]
pt2 = [originx + fFrontDropLength, 
       originy + fFrontHeight + fBackHeight]

or Preference 2
pt1 = [originx, originy + fFrontHeight + fBackHeight]
pt2 = [originx + fFrontDropLength, originy + fFrontHeight + fBackHeight]

I expect there's a combination of settings like one-line arguments and max column width (or similar), but I can't find these settings...
Note: Using an alternative formatter is acceptable. I'm not bound to AutoPep8 for any reason.

Have you tried Black? For this example, it keeps everything as one line. If you make one of the lines much longer though, it wraps it per-element.

Hi, I have tried Black - for this example, it works, but it does't work the way I want on several other cases. I'll explore those seperately. Thanks
